# In onclick event I want the pass the variable to div (I'm using single div)

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

In `onclick` event how to pass the variable to div, using that variable I want display the values in the div.

Comment: Damn, i don't even understand a little fraction of what you want. Please elaborate.

Comment: Your question is completely vague. please elaborate it properly, explaining what you need and what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, it's better to use [jQuery metadata plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata). You can put any value into a DOM element inside the `class` attribute. Here is the example:

```
<div id="some_div_id" class"default {'id': '2', 'type': 'general'}">
  div content here...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
  $("#some_div_id").click(function(){
    var data = $(this).metadata();
    //now you can access the variable, example:
    console.log(data.id);  //you will get 2 in Firebug
    console.log(data.type);  //you will get 'general' in Firebug
    //do some processing here...
    //...
  });
});
</script>
```

When writing the `div`, you can put value from the php easily:

```
<div id="some_div_id" class"default {'id': '<?php echo $id; ?>', 'type': '<?php echo $type; ?>'}">
```

I hope this is what you looking for.

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) is a cross browser javascript library. It will save you from writing a complex javascript code that will run in all modern browser.