# Passing Values to Modal Popup Using Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, popup

I want to pass button ID values into a Modal popup window when user click that particular button. Later from that passed ID I can query DB values and view in that opened modal popup window.

This is the code portion for button. Id will be assigned form DB. It is working fine.

```
<td>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="<?php echo $row["id"];?>" value="Details" onClick="popupwindow(this.id)">
</td>
```

Modal Window: Here I need to get the value form popupwindow function and query DB and view:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <!--  From the retrieved values I can query and view data here.-->
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Function for Passing values to Modal Popup Window

```
function popupwindow(id) {

// code for Pass the value to modal window

            window.location="#openModal"
            }
```

I need a code sample for popupwindow function to pass my button ID values into Modal Window. Please help me on this. I'm very new to this topic.

Comment: what do you mean by a modal window? an html popup?

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295316/in-onclick-event-i-want-the-pass-the-variable-to-divim-using-single-div

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use AJAX to query your DB and retrieve data from it, the basic template of your `popupwindow` can be like this:

```
function popupwindow(id) {

    $("#openModal .content").load("yourscript.php?id=" + escape(id), function(){
        $("#openModal").show();
    })

}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <!--  From the retrieved values I can query and view data here.-->
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onClick()`, use jQuery `click` function. Here's how:

```
$("[input[name = 'button']").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('id'); // This will give the ID of the button clicked. 
});
```

Alternatively, I'd suggest you to add a class to the buttons you want to have a modal displayed on. Here's how:

```
<td><input type="button" class="modalBtn" name="button" id="<?php echo $row["id"];?>" value="Details"></td>
```

Now, in JQuery, do the following

```
$(".modalBtn").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('id'); // This will give the ID of the button clicked. 
});
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: How to pass that ID inside popup?

Comment: Store it in a variable and pass it as an argument to the function that is loading data in the modal. Easy peasy!

Answer (score 0):

use window.location.hash for replace hash

```
function popupwindow(id) {
    window.location.hash = '#openModal'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script for loading and unloading pop up box,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
     loadPopupBox();

    $("#popupBoxClose").click( function() {           
        unloadPopupBox();
    });




    function unloadPopupBox() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
        $("#popup_box").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#mainWrapper").css({ // this is just for style       
            "opacity": "0.8" 
        });
    }   

    function loadPopupBox() {    // To Load the Popupbox
        $("#popup_box").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#mainWrapper").css({ // this is just for style
            "opacity": "0.2" 

        });        
    }       

 });  
</script>
```

Other than that you dont need to send values through the JS , JS is a client side , u cannot play with server side language , using client side.

one solution is you can use something like,

```
      window.location="#openModal?id=<?php echo json_encode($row['id']); ?>;"
```

and change the method of the form to GET instead of post.

After doing that you can write a php code , for excepting the value from $_GET and echo the modal pop-up using php.